# Mock I18n class from i18n-js to test with Jest in React Native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, ts-jest, i18n-js

I'm try to do a testing for a component where I use i18n in React Native with Expo but, I'm getting an error that say `Jest encountered an unexpected token`.

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /<app-dir>/node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { I18n } from "./I18n";
```

For the i18n, I use [Expo Localization with i18n-js](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/localization/), and for that reason I use i18n-js.

this is my implementation:

```js
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { I18n } from 'i18n-js';

import translations from './translations';

const i18n = new I18n(translations);
i18n.locale = Localization.locale.split('-')[0];
i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
i18n.enableFallback = true;

export default i18n;
export { Localization };
```

And it works in all my components, but failt the test of the components where I import this module, ex:

`import i18n from '../../../i18n';`
and later using the i18n

`<Text>{i18n.t('keyOfTranslation')}</Text>`

---

I try to mock the `i18n-js` module using:

`jest.config.ts`

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    'i18n-jss': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/i18n-jsMocked.ts'
  }
```

`i18n-jsMocked.ts`

```js
import * as origininalI18n from 'i18n-js';
const mocked = origininalI18n as jest.Mocked<typeof origininalI18n>;
export const I18n = mocked.I18n;

beforeEach(() => {
  I18n.mockClear();
});

const i18nMocked = jest.mock('i18n-js', () => {
  return {
    I18n
  };
});

export default i18nMocked;
```

and other solutions, but later I always get the error from the initialise I18n Class (`const i18n = new I18n(translations)`) with the error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _i18nJs.I18n is not a constructor

      4 | import translations from './translations';
      5 |
    > 6 | const i18n = new I18n(translations);
        |              ^
      7 | i18n.locale = Localization.locale.split('-')[0];
      8 | i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
      9 | i18n.enableFallback = true;

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/i18n/index.ts:6:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/otherFolder/MyComponent/index.tsx:17:1)
```

---

**How Can I solve it?**

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue - I am experiencing the exact same thing.

Comment: Hi @Rolchau I did an implementatition for solve it, I'll add a answer with my solve

Answer (score 2):

For solve it I do this:

`jest.config.ts`

```js
import { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)'
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/jest.setup.ts'], <-- add this
};

export default config;
```

Under my `src` folder I created a `__mocks__` folder and under it, I created a file call `jest.setup.ts`.

Later I created the files `i18n-js.ts` and `react-i18next.ts` with this implementations:

`i18n-js.ts`

```js
jest.mock('i18n-js', () => ({
  I18n: () => {
    return {
      t: jest.fn((str: string) => str)
    };
  }
}));
```

`react-i18next.ts`

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: jest.fn()
}));

const tSpy = jest.fn((str) => str);
const useTranslationSpy: any = useTranslation;

useTranslationSpy.mockReturnValue({
  t: tSpy,
  i18n: {
    changeLanguage: () => new Promise(() => {})
  }
});
```

And in the end, import that files into the `jest.setup.ts` file:

```js
import './i18n-js';
import './react-i18next';
```